# Tabularx does not work anymore

Tags: tables, tabularx

I’ve always used tabularx without any problem, but now out of nothing it doesn’t make \textwidth anymore and I don't understand why (last time I opened my document, everything was fine). Could you tell me please what’s the problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, pointlessnumbers, xcolor=dvipsnames]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\babeltags{ger=ngerman}

\usepackage{array, booktabs, boldline}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\hlineB{2}
\textsf{\textbf{Addition}} & Avant tout & Ensuite & Pour conclure \\
\hlineB{2}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `does not work anymore`? Do you get an error? If so please cite this error in your question.

Comment: tabularx doesn’t make the table as wide as the page is. So \textwidth doesn’t work (thanks for the remark, I’ve edited my post).

Comment: Why are you loading `ltablex`? If `ltablex` is removed it works as it should, so it more seems appropriate to change the title to be about `ltablex`

Comment: From manual: "In other words, the specified width is treated as the maximum allowed and not the exact width of the table.". Make your example minimal by removing unused packages,...

Comment: also you have a space to the left of tabularx from the space after `1.5}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your document example can be compile without any error or warnins, i.e. it works as expected
- You should be aware, that `ltablex` has a features that in cases, when contents in columns are shorter as would be at `X` column when only `tabularx` is loaded, reduce their width to natural width of columns contents (what happens in your case).
- Your problems can be solved on two ways:

  - from preamble remove the `ltablex` package and use some other package which combine  `longtable` and `tabularx`, for example `xltabular`
  - if for some reason you need to use `ltablex`, than add `\keepXColumns` to document preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, pointlessnumbers, xcolor=dvipsnames]{scrreprt}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, latexsym}
\usepackage{boldline, ltablex}
\newcolumntype{L}{ >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\keepXColumns

\babeltags{ger=ngerman}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}
                             LLL}
\hlineB{2}
\textsf{\textbf{Addition}} & Avant tout & Ensuite & Pour conclure \\
\hlineB{2}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)